# meaning of 「気遣ひいたすも一致なれば」

Tags: meaning

Looking at the definition for 一致 I can't seem to understand the example sentence for the second meaning

> ２ ごく普通の道理。
>   「気遣ひいたすも一致なれば」

The second meaning for 一致 means "common sense" I think, but I'm not sure what "気遣ひいたす" is conveying, since I've seen "気遣い"　"気遣う" and　"気遣わしい", but never "気遣ひ"

Comment: 「一致」の２番目の意味が次のところに記載されているのは確認しましたが、narutoさんの回答にあるとおり、「common sense」のような意味で現在は全く使われておりませんので、古い日本語を勉強する以外の目的では覚える必要はないと言えます。https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/13474/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 気遣ひ is just [気遣い](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E9%81%A3%E3%81%84) written in [historical kana orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_kana_orthography). Note that big monolingual dictionaries can have historical definitions of a word, and this example is from a book written in the 18th century. This meaning of 一致 has long been obsolete, and I did not know such a meaning of 一致. In modern Japanese, it probably means 気遣いをするのも当然だから.